# Rails & Heroku: Can I share database between two apps?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I have two similar applications on heroku, is there a way I can make them share databases ? at least for User authentication ?

---

Right after I got answer to this question the following came to my mind:
I will be using the multi app architecture for a long term / heavy network system:

1- First issue I will face is that the more processes I will have interacting with the shared resource, the more likely I will face scaling/performance and timing issues.

2- Complexity of the models, because at some point I'm planning to use rails engines, and I realized it will be a mess of data_model_prefixes.

3- Costy ? Monolithic apps on 1 db VS Many apps.

I found a few other solutions regarding this issue or let's say approach:

1- Letting every application have their own database, then maybe using an api to share the common tables between the applications.

2- If I decided to go to AWS, I can use  Amazon RDS plugin that lets model being access from different databases uing ActiveRecord.
sources:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5986996/539075

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3479315/539075

and TaskRabbit explained some part of this very well:

http://tech.taskrabbit.com/blog/2014/02/11/rails-4-engines/

The ugly part is that I have angular on top of Rails, it's just hard to scale at some point!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5981508/share-database-between-2-apps-in-heroku

Comment: Thanks, I should have searched better, AH!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>heroku config | grep DATABASE
```

This will give you the database url 
now you can use these variable values for the second app.

```
heroku config:set KEY1=VALUE1 [KEY2=VALUE2 ...]
```

These credentials can be found from heroku dashboard.
Tell me if this works for you.

Comment: Thanks, Now I just realized there are consequences with that :)!

Comment: Will you please share your concerns for others as this is a very common question.

Comment: Will do, I will add it to my question.

Comment: added some details :)!, not sure if it will be helpful! I hope I would have time right a blog about this.